# Wordpress site, 404 errors for image request, yet images render

Tags: php, wordpress, image, http-status-code-404

This is what it looks like:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[image http://appliancerepairalamedaca.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/samsung-refrigerator-repair-150x150@2x.png](http://appliancerepairalamedaca.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/samsung-refrigerator-repair-150x150@2x.png)

Yet the images render on the page with no problem, and the paths seem fine. Anyone got an idea on this one?

Comment: Nope, image does not render fine.

Comment: Maybe htaccess issue? Check the .htaccess  file

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).